# Google Cloud Functions with Trace Agent connection

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-trace

I need to connect monitoring and tracing tools for our application. Our main code is on Express 4 running on Google Cloud Functions. All requests incoming from front nginx proxy server that handle domain and pretty routes names. Unfortunately, trace agent traces this requests, that coming on nginx front proxy without any additional information, and this is not enough to collect useful information about app. I found the Stack Driver custom API, which, as I understand might help to collect appropriate data on runtime, but I don't understand how I can connect it to Google Cloud Functions app. All other examples saying, that we must extend our startup script, but Google Cloud Functions fully automated thing, there is no such possibility here.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution. I included `require("@google-cloud/trace-agent");` not at the top of the *index.js*. It should be included **before** all other modules. After that it started to work.

Comment: May I know how you assured calling it before all other modules?

Comment: @Ayyappa, First line of your main file, one that will be called from cli. Or you might use --require flag on cli on node, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Placing require("@google-cloud/trace-agent") as the very first import didn't work for me. I still kept getting:

```
ERROR:@google-cloud/trace-agent: express tracing might not work as /var/tmp/worker/node_modules/express/index.js was loaded before the trace agent was initialized.
```

However I managed to work around it by manually patching express:

```
var traceApi = require('@google-cloud/trace-agent').get();
require("@google-cloud/trace-agent/src/plugins/plugin-express")[0].patch(
  require(Object.keys(require('module')._cache).find( _ => _.indexOf("express") !== -1)),
  traceApi
);
```

Comment: Well, I also faced this error when I returned back to *trace-agent* on another project. We didn't need trace-agent so critically on those project so we postponed the integration. I checked old project that already had established *trace-agent* and no new errors appeared. For now it is working well in context of my initial question.

Comment: I have one addition to this error, that you mentioned. I think, that this error actually belongs to root level express application of GCF. I have an assumption, that user defined HTTP GCF are wrapped in express application, and root level express (that are not controlled by us and was defined by Google's engineers) passing request to our exported function that, handling then requests. In any case, connecting trace-agent as it was proposed by documentation is working even with this error.